# How to create JSON data using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I want to create a JSON Object dynamically with the following format:

```
{
    "deleteId":[1,2,3],
    "pointId":[1,2,3],
    "update":[
        {
            "what":"mission",
            "id":1,
            "value":"adsda"
        },
        {
            "what":"mission",
            "id":2,
            "value":"sadjajks"
        },
        {
            "what":"point",
            "id":3,
            "value":"asjdjh"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting data in my controller as shown below.

```
edit_vision_mission.controller('edit_vision_missionCtrl',['$scope','$http', 'getMissionDataService', function($scope, $http, getMissionDataService) {
    $scope.visiontext = "Here is the content of vision";
    getMissionDataService.getMissionData().success(function(response){
       $scope.missions = response;
       $scope.len = $scope.missions.length;
    });
    var jsonData = {};
    jsonData.deleteId = [];
    jsonData.pointId = [];
    jsonData.update = [];
    $scope.deletemission = function(missionid){
        jsonData.deleteId.push(missionid);
        alert("deleted " + jsonData.deleteId);
    };

    $scope.deletemissionpoints = function(missionpointid){
        jsonData.pointId.push(missionpointid);
        console.log(missionpointid);
        alert("deleted " + jsonData.pointId);
    };

    $scope.updatemission = function(missionid, info){
       var updateinfo = {"what" : "mission", "id" : missionid, "value" : info};
       jsonData.update.push(updateinfo);
       alert("updated " + jsonData.update);
    };

    $scope.updatemissionpoints = function(missionpointid, info){
        var updateinfo = {"what" : "point", "id" : missionpointid, "value" : info};
       jsonData.update.push(updateinfo);
       alert("updated " + jsonData.update);
    };
}]);
```

I'm struggling to make the JSON data of the above format, `jsonData.update` does not show anything in the alert.

I needed help on how to make JSON of the above format.

I also wanted to know the way to test JSON data in the front end?

Comment: Just for clarification, in your top example you have `Update` with a capital `U`, and in the code you have it with lowercase `u`. Which is correct?

Comment: above JSON is the sample..., lowercase u is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsonData is an object. So your alert should show `"updated" [ object Object ]`.

All the methods above seems fine.

To view your object in more clean way use developer tools by chrome. There is a last tab called **console**. You can open up developer tools by right clicking on your page and select **inspect element**.

You need to update your code to following,

Rather than doing this `alert( "updated" + jsonData.update )`, do `console.log( jsonData.update )`

Mixing 2 types in `console.log()` doesn't allow it to parse.

E.g. from your above sample & code.

```
var sample = '{"deleteId":[1,2,3],"pointId":[1,2,3],"update":[ {"what":"mission","id":1,"value":"adsda" }, {"what":"mission","id":2,"value":"sadjajks" }, {"what":"point","id":3,"value":"asjdjh" }]}';

var jsonData = {};

jsonData.deleteId = [];
jsonData.pointId = [];
jsonData.update = [];

var deletemission = function(missionid){
    jsonData.deleteId.push(missionid);
    console.log (  " deleted " );
    console.log ( jsonData.deleteId );
};

var deletemissionpoints = function(missionpointid){
    jsonData.pointId.push(missionpointid);
    console.log (  " deleted " );
    console.log ( jsonData.pointId );
};

var updatemission = function(missionid, info){
   var updateinfo = {"what" : "mission", "id" : missionid, "value" : info};
   jsonData.update.push(updateinfo);
   console.log (  " updated " );
   console.log ( jsonData.update );
};

var updatemissionpoints = function(missionpointid, info){
    var updateinfo = {"what" : "point", "id" : missionpointid, "value" : info};
   jsonData.update.push(updateinfo);
   console.log (  " updated " );
   console.log ( jsonData.update );
};

sample = JSON.parse( sample );

for( var i = 0 ; i < sample.deleteId.length; i++ ) {
  deletemission( sample.deleteId[i] );
}

for( i = 0 ; i < sample.pointId.length; i++ ) {
  deletemissionpoints( sample.pointId[i] );
}

for( i = 0 ; i < sample.update.length; i++ ) {

  if ( sample.update[i].what == "mission") {
    updatemission(  sample.update[i].id , sample.update[i].value )
  } else {
    updatemissionpoints(  sample.update[i].id , sample.update[i].value )
  }

}

console.log( jsonData );
```

Comment: in the console, it shows `object, object`, it is not showing the actual object data....does it mean that the jsonData is being formed correctly?